# Can I use wiggle bones in Blender 4.0 or do I have to revert to an older version?

Tags: animation

I have the basic values in the N panel under the Animation tab.
But I don't know where to set values for a wiggle bone in Blender v4.0.
I can't find out where to change the jiggle values.

Comment: it seems to be still here in the Bone panel? https://www.zupimages.net/up/24/02/23pb.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded an older version = wiggle_bones1_5_b14_fix.py 
 and it works as seen: zupimages.net/up/24/02/23pb.jpg 
But my blender-wiggle-2 doesn't function.

Comment: I haven't tested in the latest versions of Blender. If it doesn't work there's another addon called Bonedynamics and that is even simpler from what I remember: https://blendermarket.com/products/bonedynamics